# HTML5 draw encrypted video frame to canvas (Encrypted Media Extensions with clearkey)

Tags: javascript, html, video, canvas, encryption

I am trying to draw frames from a HTML5 video element to a canvas using Javascript in which the video (webm VP9) has been encrypted with clearkey. I am using EME to decrypt it in Chrome. It appears that Chrome >= 55 does not allow CanvasContext2D.drawImage when using EME (Encrypted Media Extensions). The video itself is playing nicely, but I am not able to grab any frames.

Does anyone know a workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no workaround. If there was a way to read raw pixel data from an encrypted frame, it would make DRM pointless. Hence doing what you want is specifically disallowed.